# Insert regular double quotes in LaTeX mode with AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, elisp, auctex

How do I rebind the double quote key to simply insert a double quote in a LaTeX buffer with AUCTex enabled?

I tried redefining TeX open and close quote, but that didn't seem to work.

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          '(progn
             (setq-default TeX-close-quote "\"")
             (setq-default tex-close-quote "\"")
             (setq-default TeX-open-quote "\"")
             (setq-default tex-open-quote "\"")
             (setq-default TeX-quote-after-quote t)))
```

**Update**

The above code and the accepted answer would have worked, except that I have `smartparens` enabled.  Smartparens *helpfully* redefines the quote key to insert LaTeX quotes.  The code to use normal quotes is below:

```
(eval-after-load 'latex
  '(progn
     (require 'smartparens-latex)
     ;; removes the double quote trigger binding. Now smartparens will 
     ;; insert a regular double quote
     (sp-local-pair 'latex-mode "``" "''" :trigger "\"" :actions :rem)))
```

Comment: How about?:  `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda () (setq TeX-close-quote "\"") (setq TeX-open-quote "\"")))`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can unset the `auctex` binding as:

```
(defun my-hook ()
  (local-unset-key "\""))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-hook)
```

Alternately, if you want to use the smart quotes most of the time but occasionally insert a literal double quote, just do `C-q "`.

Comment: Just curious. What the `C-q` command does?